# Share module between Gradle and Maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, pom.xml

I have 2 projects (Android and Spring) and I want to share DTO layer between them.

Spring is a Maven based project.
Gradle is Gradle based.

How can I extract set of classes (packages) between these two projects?

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the classes you want to share in a specific module.

Build this module (jar) and publish it on an artifact repository (like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products-overview), or [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/))

Then, you can easily depend on this module from a maven or gradle based project

Answer (score 1):

Both maven and gradle can publish and consume artifacts (jars) from a maven repository. This can either be the maven local directory or a repository on the cloud (eg [jfrog artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) or [sonatype nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/))

Gradle will create a [PublishToMavenLocal](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/tasks/PublishToMavenLocal.html) task for each [MavenPublication](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html) you declare in your build so when working locally you can invoke this which will make jars built in gradle available to your local maven builds.

If you declare a [mavenLocal()](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler:mavenLocal%28%29) repository in your gradle build then gradle will lookup artifacts from there. So any jars you publish from maven command line can be used locally in gradle.